# Transform json data to python dataframe to export to a Dbtable or save as csv

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I am new to python.
Kindly help me with this.

I have the following sample json data in a json file, sometimes thousands or more records

Beautify json version

[Beautify json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZbEn.jpg)

Raw data

**{
"@odata.context": "https://example.com/services/api/x/odata/api/views/$metadata#vw_rpt_review_response_comment",
"value": [
{
"pr_comment_id": 1,
"pr_comment": "Test Comment"
},
{
"pr_comment_id": 2,
"pr_comment": "Test Comment"
},
{
"pr_comment_id": 3,
"pr_comment": "Test Comment"
}
],

```
"@odata.nextLink": "https://example.com/services/api/x/odata/api/views/$metadata#vw_rpt_review_response_comment?$skip=1000"
```

}
{
"@odata.context": "https://example.com/services/api/x/odata/api/views/$metadata#vw_rpt_review_response_comment",
"value": [
{
"pr_comment_id": 4,
"pr_comment": "Test Comment"
},
{
"pr_comment_id": 5,
"pr_comment": "Test Comment"
},
{
"pr_comment_id": 6,
"pr_comment": "Test Comment"
}
],

```
"@odata.nextLink": "https://example.com/services/api/x/odata/api/views/$metadata#vw_rpt_review_response_comment?$skip=2000"
```

}**

I need to convert it to a dataframe like below to export into a db table or save as csv

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfhSq.png)

Below is the code i have tried

```
import pandas as pd
import json
df = pd.read_json(r"path/output.json", lines=True)
print(df)
```

Also

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas import json_normalize
info = json.loads(response)
```

But i am getting the error as

**loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
ValueError: Expected object or value**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have a list in one of the JSON entries the result is a non-standard JSON, that's why you're having troubles. If you want to create a data frame with the comments ids and the comments simply iterate through the data.

```
inter=jsonobj["value"]
ids=[]
comments=[]

for val in inter:
    ids.append(val["pr_comment_id"])
    comments.append(val["pr_comment"])
    
data=pd.DataFrame()
data["pr_comment_id"]=ids
data["pr_comment"]=comments
```

If you have many json objects, iterate through all of them and leave the data frame declaration to the end.

Comment: thank you for the assistance, it worked! but like you said , yes, its a non-standard json, i need to sort it out before parsing into dataframe. Please find this link, if you can help me out. Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67745581/python-code-to-download-specific-json-key-value-data-through-rest-api-calls