# Python code to Download Specific JSON key value data through REST API calls

Tags: python, json, api

I am trying to write a code in python which download only specific key value in the Calls.

So the solution might be

1. Downloading the Raw data and later removing the unwanted through regex or
   2)Applying specific process in API calls itself which downloads and appends only "Value".

Note - Code for access_token not included.

My Basic code from postman was

```
url = "https://xyz-stg.csod.com/services/api/x/odata/api/views/vw_rpt_performance_comment"

payload={}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
  'Cookie': 'ASP.NET_SessionId=hsylq0qqp; Cookie_2=value'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload).json()

print(response, file=open(r"C:\Users\path\Desktop\Python script\output.json", 'w', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore'))


while response['@odata.nextLink']:
    url = response['@odata.nextLink']
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload).json()
    #response.extend(response)


    print(response, file=open(r"C:\Users\path\Desktop\Python script\output.json", 'a', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore'))
    break
```

Raw json output data

```
*{ "@odata.context": "https://example.com/services/api/x/odata/api/views/$metadata#vw_rpt_review_response_comment", "value": [ { "pr_comment_id": 1, "pr_comment": "Test Comment" }, { "pr_comment_id": 2, "pr_comment": "Test Comment" }, { "pr_comment_id": 3, "pr_comment": "Test Comment" } ],
"@odata.nextLink": "https://example.com/services/api/x/odata/api/views/$metadata#vw_rpt_review_response_comment?$skip=1000"
} { "@odata.context": "https://example.com/services/api/x/odata/api/views/$metadata#vw_rpt_review_response_comment", "value": [ { "pr_comment_id": 4, "pr_comment": "Test Comment" }, { "pr_comment_id": 5, "pr_comment": "Test Comment" }, { "pr_comment_id": 6, "pr_comment": "Test Comment" } ],
"@odata.nextLink": "https://example.com/services/api/x/odata/api/views/$metadata#vw_rpt_review_response_comment?$skip=2000"
}*
```

**[Beautify json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZbEn.jpg)**

**REQUIRED OUTPUT**

```
*{ "value": [ { "pr_comment_id": 1, "pr_comment": "Test Comment" }, { "pr_comment_id": 2, "pr_comment": "Test Comment" }, { "pr_comment_id": 3, "pr_comment": "Test Comment" } , { "pr_comment_id": 4, "pr_comment": "Test Comment" }, { "pr_comment_id": 5, "pr_comment": "Test Comment" }, { "pr_comment_id": 6, "pr_comment": "Test Comment" } ]
}*
```

**[Beautify json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od73j.jpg)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your individual response come through, you can create a list of the values using `extend` (vs `append`). Then create your final dictionary.

Here's a mockup of one way to implement -collect all the response, then iterate over the list. Otherwise you can parse each response as they come in.

```
response1 = { "@odata.context": "https://example.com/services/api/x/odata/api/views/$metadata#vw_rpt_review_response_comment", "value": [ { "pr_comment_id": 1, "pr_comment": "Test Comment" }, { "pr_comment_id": 2, "pr_comment": "Test Comment" }, { "pr_comment_id": 3, "pr_comment": "Test Comment" } ],
"@odata.nextLink": "https://example.com/services/api/x/odata/api/views/$metadata#vw_rpt_review_response_comment?$skip=1000"
} 

response2 = { "@odata.context": "https://example.com/services/api/x/odata/api/views/$metadata#vw_rpt_review_response_comment", "value": [ { "pr_comment_id": 4, "pr_comment": "Test Comment" }, { "pr_comment_id": 5, "pr_comment": "Test Comment" }, { "pr_comment_id": 6, "pr_comment": "Test Comment" } ],
"@odata.nextLink": "https://example.com/services/api/x/odata/api/views/$metadata#vw_rpt_review_response_comment?$skip=2000"
}

value_list = []
for resp in [response1, response2]:
    # print(resp['value'])
    value_list.extend(resp['value'])

my_dict = {'value': value_list}
my_dict
```

Output

```
{'value': [{'pr_comment_id': 1, 'pr_comment': 'Test Comment'},
  {'pr_comment_id': 2, 'pr_comment': 'Test Comment'},
  {'pr_comment_id': 3, 'pr_comment': 'Test Comment'},
  {'pr_comment_id': 4, 'pr_comment': 'Test Comment'},
  {'pr_comment_id': 5, 'pr_comment': 'Test Comment'},
  {'pr_comment_id': 6, 'pr_comment': 'Test Comment'}]}
```

Comment: thank you for your response, now i wrote a script which saves the entire API data into a json file in the similar format
resp0 = { data
}
resp1 = { data
}
resp2 = { data
} so on..
now i am stuck on how to execute the python script which you have provided from a json file
Kindly help @Jonathan leon

Comment: Start a new question specific to issue. Which is how to parse parse json from file and give structure if your file. There are plenty of examples on SO how to read and parse files. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your response@Jonathan Leon, kindly find the question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/67766448/15945458