# python code to read and parse a string file type line by line and get the specific json key value

Tags: python, json, dataframe, parsing

I have a file, which is of type string, which stores all the REST API JSON data from multiple pages, in below format

```py
resp0 ={ "@odata.context": "https://example.com/services/api/x/odata/api/views/$metadata#vw_rpt_review_response_comment", "value": [ { "pr_comment_id": 1, "pr_comment": "Test Comment" }, { "pr_comment_id": 2, "pr_comment": "Test Comment" }, { "pr_comment_id": 3, "pr_comment": "Test Comment" } ],
"@odata.nextLink": "https://example.com/services/api/x/odata/api/views/$metadata#vw_rpt_review_response_comment?$skip=1000"
} 

resp1 ={ "@odata.context": "https://example.com/services/api/x/odata/api/views/$metadata#vw_rpt_review_response_comment", "value": [ { "pr_comment_id": 4, "pr_comment": "Test Comment" }, { "pr_comment_id": 5, "pr_comment": "Test Comment" }, { "pr_comment_id": 6, "pr_comment": "Test Comment" } ],
"@odata.nextLink": "https://example.com/services/api/x/odata/api/views/$metadata#vw_rpt_review_response_comment?$skip=2000"
}*

..so on
```

I want the file to be changed as

```py
{ "value": [ { "pr_comment_id": 1, "pr_comment": "Test Comment" }, { "pr_comment_id": 2, "pr_comment": "Test Comment" }, { "pr_comment_id": 3, "pr_comment": "Test Comment" } , { "pr_comment_id": 4, "pr_comment": "Test Comment" }, { "pr_comment_id": 5, "pr_comment": "Test Comment" }, { "pr_comment_id": 6, "pr_comment": "Test Comment" } ]
}
```

[beautify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od73j.jpg)

So that my final aim is to convert to dataframe, like below to input into a db table.

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfhSq.png)

Below is the code I am trying yet

```
with open(r'C:\Users\path\abc.json') as source:
    json_source = source.read()
    for resp0 in json_source:
        print(resp0['value'])
```

Comment: is this really in your file? resp0 = and resp1 =? If so, you should create your file with only the dictionaries, it'd be easier to deal with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a file without preceding resp0 and resp1. That's how this would work to create your output. Maybe your file is cleaner than the examples above but this is the only way I made it work

```
with open('output.json') as data:
    responses = data.read().splitlines()
    value_list = []
    for resp in responses:
        if resp: # because you have blank lines between responses
            print(json.loads(resp.strip())) # needed to strip extraneous characters
            value_list.extend(json.loads(resp.strip())['value'])
my_dict = {'value': value_list}
my_dict
```

Comment: hey @jonathan - I have intentionally added few lines of script to prefix resp0, resp1 before each response, I thought you suggested, but now i removed them now and exec your script,  and it perfectly worked now, Thank you so much! :)